# solder vs smolder

Tags: word-choice

What are the differences between solder and smolder?

Which one is more proper in the following example:

> the cpu (or network card) is soldered/smoldered onto the motherboard.

Btw, I have seen both used.

Comment: Apart from the meaning, note also that they are pronounced differently (the *L* in solder is silent).

Comment: @Era: apparently, there are different pronunciations of "solder": [What is the correct pronunciation of the word “solder”? (ELU)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-the-word-solder)

Comment: An *intransitive* verb, **smolder** cannot be used in a passive construction.  For example, a pile of leaves is smoldering and may burst into flame.  Nothing is smoldering the leaves. The leaves are themselves smoldering. Smolder means to be on fire just a little bit, giving off smoke.

Answer (score 2):

Soldered means by the use of molten metal (the solder).

Smoldered means slowly burning.

While applying the heat for soldering something (like the circuit board) might smolder.

Two pieces of plastic might be bonded by applying heat; this could be regarded as smoldering, but it is a play on words. They would really be melted together.

Comment: This might also be an [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn).